# Passing binding back to parent's parent view

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have 4 views.

1. Grandparent
2. Parent
3. Child
4. EditView

Grandparent has a navigation link to Parent, and Parent a navigation link to Child. Child has a button which initializes a @State variable, location (a class), from Grandparent, via a binding in Parent and a binding in Child. That same button also updates a @State variable, showEditView, from Grandparent (via bindings again), which shows the EditView.

There are 11 lines which are currently commented out. If they are commented out, the app throws a "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil..." error when I tap the button in the Child view. If either section is uncommented, the button does not throw an error.

It also works if I pass the bound location to the EditView, not property itself like I'm currently doing, where it is then wrapped as an @ObservedObject.

I don't understand what is going on here. The only thing I can of is that, when it's working, SwiftUI is updating the location property because it's used in the body. If that is the case, that seems to indicate that I have to include a hidden Text view of this property every time I want to do have properties passed around this way.

Grandparent

```
import SwiftUI

struct Grandparent: View {
    @State var location: Location!
    @State var showEditView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Parent(location: $location, showEditView: $showEditView)) {
                    Text("Navigate")
                }
// //               section 1
//                if location != nil {
//                    Text(location.name)
//                } else {
//                    Text("No location yet")
//                }
            }
// //            section 2
//            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
//                Button("Edit"){
//                    showEditView = true
//                }
//                .disabled(location == nil)
//            )
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $showEditView) {
            EditView(placemark: location, dismiss: { showEditView = false })
        }
    }
}
```

Parent

```
import SwiftUI

struct Parent: View {
    @Binding var location: Location!
    @Binding var showEditView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: Child(location: $location, showEditView: $showEditView),
            label: {
                Text("Child")
            })
    }
}
```

Child

```
import SwiftUI

struct Child: View {
    @Binding var location: Location!
    @Binding var showEditView: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Button("Make location") {
            location = Location(name: "Lebanon")
            showEditView = true
        }
    }
}
```

EditView

```
import SwiftUI

struct EditView: View {
    @ObservedObject var placemark: Location
    var dismiss: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text(placemark.name)
                .navigationTitle("Edit place")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Done") { dismiss() })
        }
    }
}
```

Location

```
import Foundation

class Location: ObservableObject {
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    @Published var name: String
}
```

Comment: Have you tried not to use forced-wrapping optional 
`@State var location: Location?`

Comment: You also probably want `@StateObject` rather than `@State`.... and it also makes no sense not to have this initialized

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't declare your `Location` as `!` and then do `nil` checking on it. Using `!` is sort of asking for a crash to happen. I think what you're encountering is a the `sheet` getting rendered before `location` is set. There aren't any guarantees about *when* in the run loop a `@State` variable gets set, so it's better to account for scenarios where it is `nil` (and definitely not using `!` to force unwrap it).

Secondly, at least given the scenario you have here, you probably shouldn't be using a `class` for `Location` -- it should just be a `struct`.

Eventually, you are going to run into a little bit of complexity, because judging by your View's name, you want to edit the `Location` at some point. This becomes a little more tricky with an `Optional`, since things like `TextField` want non-optional values, but this can be solved in various was (see where I used `nonNilBinding`).

Something like this is *definitely* a more safe approach than what you're currently doing. It may not be *exactly* what you want, but hopefully it can get you on the right path.

```
struct Location {
    var name : String
}

struct Grandparent: View {
    @State var location: Location?
    @State var showEditView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Parent(location: $location, showEditView: $showEditView)) {
                    Text("Navigate")
                }
                if let location = location {
                    Text(location.name)
                } else {
                    Text("No location yet")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .sheet(isPresented: $showEditView) {
                EditView(placemark: $location, dismiss: { showEditView = false })
            }
        }
    }
}


struct Parent: View {
    @Binding var location: Location?
    @Binding var showEditView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: Child(location: $location, showEditView: $showEditView),
            label: {
                Text("Child")
            })
    }
}

struct Child: View {
    @Binding var location: Location?
    @Binding var showEditView: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Button("Make location") {
            location = Location(name: "Lebanon")
            showEditView = true
        }
    }
}

struct EditView: View {
    @Binding var placemark: Location?
    var dismiss: () -> Void
    
    var nonNilBinding : Binding<Location> {
        .init { () -> Location in
            placemark ?? Location(name:"Default")
        } set: { (newValue) in
            placemark = newValue
        }

    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TextField("Name", text: nonNilBinding.name)
                    .navigationTitle("Edit place")
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Done") { dismiss() })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought implicitly unwrapped optional were silly when I first read about them, but I came across a use case sooner than I expected, which is essentially what I'm trying to replicate here. Using MapKit, I have an annotation (what I'm using location for here). It's implicitly unwrapped because when the view loads, it's nil. It only gets edited after it's been created, like I'm doing with location here. When debugging, I see the location gets created, but, like you said, "the sheet getting rendered before location is set."

Comment: This is why location is a class--it's merely a stand-in for what I really want in there, which is a MKPointAnnotation, which, yes, though a pain in the butt, gets updated via an extension and a computed property with a getter and a setter. Although now I'm talking about optional properties on the optional object, so it's a bit different.

Comment: The implicitly-unwrapped optionals seem like a pretty risky plan. Regarding the annotations, the way I've always dealt with those is generating them dynamically for the map -- not holding references to them.